# why my assembly program is not creating/removing directory/file

Tags: assembly, dos, masm

My teacher assigned me a project to write a DOS program in assembly. The program should create/remove/rename file/directory and change file attributes. I am using masm611.
I 've included dos.inc in my program. The program is divided in two files, 1st is pro.asm and 2nd is code.asm.

//dos.inc

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
;  Syntax:    @MkDir path [,segment]
;
;             @RmDir path [,segment]
;
;             @ChDir path [,segment]
;
;  Summary:   Creates, deletes, or changes to the specified directory
;
;  Arguments: <path>        Offset of ASCIIZ string containing
;                           directory. Must be offset address.
;
;             <segment>     Segment of path; DS if none given.
;
;  Returns:   If carry: set, error code in AX
;
;  Modifies:  AX, DX; DS if segment changed
;
;  Uses:      Interrupt 21h Function 39h
;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@MkDir MACRO path:REQ, segmnt
    __LdAdr dx, <path>
    IFNB    <segmnt>
        __LdSeg ds, <segmnt>
    ENDIF
    mov     ah, 39h
    int     21h
ENDM

; 3Ah
@RmDir MACRO path:REQ, segmnt
    __LdAdr dx, <path>
    IFNB    <segmnt>
        __LdSeg ds, <segmnt>
    ENDIF
    mov     ah, 3Ah
    int     21h
ENDM

; 3Bh
@ChDir MACRO path:REQ, segmnt
    __LdAdr dx, <path>
    IFNB    <segmnt>
        __LdSeg ds, <segmnt>
    ENDIF
    mov     ah, 3Bh
    int     21h
ENDM

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
;  Syntax:    @DelFile path [,segment]
;
;  Summary:   Deletes a specified file
;
;  Arguments: <path>        Offset of ASCIIZ file specification. Must
;                           be an offset address.
;
;             <segment>     Segment of path; DS if none given.
;
;  Returns:   If carry: set, error code in AX
;
;  Modifies:  AX, DX; DS if segment changed
;
;  Uses:      Interrupt 21h Function 41h
;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@DelFile MACRO path:REQ, segmnt
    __LdAdr dx, <path>
    IFNB    <segmnt>
        __LdSeg ds, <segmnt>
    ENDIF
    mov     ah, 41h
    int     21h
ENDM

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
;  Syntax:    @MakeFile path [,[attrib] [,[segment] [,kind]]]
;
;  Summary:   Creates a file
;
;  Arguments: <path>        ASCIIZ string of file. Must be an offset
;                           address.
;
;             <attrib>      File attribute; 0 is default if none given.
;
;             <segment>     Segment of address string; DS if not given.
;
;             <kind>        If none given, a file is created even if one
;                           already exists. Under DOS 3.x, "tmp" can be
;                           given to create a unique file or "new" to
;                           create a file only if one doesn't already
;                           exist.
;
;  Returns:   If carry: clear, file handle in AX
;
;  Modifies:  AX, DX, CX; DS if segment changed
;
;  Uses:      Interrupt 21h Function 3Ch, 5Ah, 5Bh
;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@MakeFile MACRO path:REQ, atrib:=<0>, segmnt, kind
    IFDIF   <atrib>, <0>
        mov     cx, atrib
    ELSE
        sub     cx, cx
    ENDIF
    __LdAdr dx, <path>
    IFNB    <segmnt>
        __LdSeg ds, <segmnt>
    ENDIF
    IFIDNI  <kind>, <tmp>
        mov     ah, 5Ah
    ELSEIFIDNI <kind>, <new>
        mov    ah, 5Bh
    ELSE
        mov    ah, 3Ch
    ENDIF
    int     21h
ENDM
```

// pro.asm

```
enter code here
include dos.inc
include bios.inc
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

LF EQU 0ah
CR EQU 0dh
MSG1 DB 0ah,0dh,"1. Create directory",LF,CR
MSG2 DB "2. Create file",LF,CR
MSG3 DB "3. Delete directory",LF,CR
MSG4 DB "4. Delete file",LF,CR
MSG5 DB "5. Rename directory",LF,CR
MSG6 DB "6. Rename file",LF,CR
MSG7 DB "7. Change attributes",LF,CR
MSG8 DB "8. Exit $",LF,CR
PATH DB "c:\mydir",0
PATHF DB "C:\abc.exe",0
AnyKeyMsg DB LF,CR,"Press any key to continue...$",LF,CR

.code
main PROC



MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

CALL clearAllReg
CALL start


main ENDP

include code.asm

End main
```

// code.asm

```
start PROC

;this function starts the program
;input=none ouput=none
;MOV ah,0ah
;MOV DX,SI
;INT 21h
do:

    @cls
    CALL showDate
    CALL showMenu
    CALL newLine
    CALL getCharInput
    CMP BL,49   ;49 is ASCI for 1
    JE CDirectory   ;if BL is equals to 49 then jump to create directory
    CMP BL,50   ;50 is ASCI for 2
    JE CFile    ;if BL is equals to 50 then jump to create file
    CMP BL,51   ;51 is ASCI for 3
    JE DDirectory   ;if BL is equals to 51 then jump to delete directory
    CMP BL,52   ;52 is ASCI for 4
    JE DFile    ;if BL is equals to 52 then jump to delete file
    CMP BL,53   ;53 is ASCI for 5
    JE RDirectory   ;if BL is equals to 53 then jump to rename directory
    CMP BL,54   ;54 is ASCI for 6
    JE RFile    ;if BL is equals to 54 then jump to rename file
    CMP BL,55   ;55 is ASCI for 7
    JE ChAttributes ;if BL is equals to 55 then jump to change attributes of a file
    CMP BL,56   ; 56 is ASCI for 8
    JE Exit     ; until BL equals to 56
    JMP do

CDirectory:

    CALL makeDir
    JMP do

CFile:

    CALL makeFile
    JMP do

DDirectory:

    CALL rmDir
    JMP do

DFile:
    CALL rmFile
    JMP do

RDirectory:

    CALL rnDir
    JMP do
RFile:

    CALL rnFile
    JMP do

ChAttributes:

    CALL chFAttrib
    JMP do

Exit:
    @exit
RET

start EndP

clearAllReg PROC

;this function sets AX,BX,CX and DX equals to 0
;input=none output=none

MOV AX,0
MOV BX,0
MOV CX,0
MOV DX,0
RET

clearAllReg EndP

showMenu PROC

;this function show menu on the screen
;input=none output=DX

LEA DX,MSG1
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
RET

showMenu EndP

makeDir PROC
;MOV ah,2
;MOV dl,'a'
;INT 21h
MOV AX,offset PATH
@MkDir AX
CALL pressAnyKey
RET
makeDir EndP

makeFile PROC
;MOV ah,2
;MOV dl,'b'
;INT 21h
MOV AX,offset PATHF
@MakeFile AX
CALL pressAnyKey
RET
makeFile EndP

rmDir PROC
;MOV ah,2
;MOV dl,'c'
;INT 21h
MOV AX,offset PATH
@RmDir AX
CALL pressAnyKey
RET
rmDir EndP

rmFile PROC
;MOV ah,2
;MOV dl,'d'
;INT 21h
MOV AX,offset PATHF
@DelFile AX
CALL pressAnyKey
RET
rmFile EndP


rnDir PROC
MOV ah,2
MOV dl,'e'
INT 21h
CALL pressAnyKey
RET
rnDir EndP

rnFile PROC
MOV ah,2
MOV dl,'f'
INT 21h
CALL pressAnyKey
RET
rnFile EndP

chFAttrib PROC
MOV ah,2
MOV dl,'g'
INT 21h
CALL pressAnyKey
RET
chFAttrib EndP

newLine PROC

;Adds new line
;Input=none output=none

MOV DL,LF
MOV AH,2
INT 21h
MOV DL,CR
INT 21h
RET

newLine ENDP

getCharInput PROC

;this function takes input from user
;input=none output=BX

PUSH AX     ;saving state
CALL newLine
MOV dl,'?'
MOV AH,2
INT 21h
MOV AH,1
INT 21h
MOV BX,AX
POP AX      ;restoring state
RET

getCharInput EndP

pressAnyKey PROC
PUSH AX     ;Saving state

LEA DX,AnyKeyMsg
MOV AH,9
INT 21h
MOV AH,1
INT 21h

POP AX      ;restoring state
RET
pressAnyKey EndP

showDate PROC

@GetTime
RET
showDate EndP
```

Comment: So what is the problem..?

Comment: its not creating directory

Comment: Invisible code is really hard to debug! I'd be willing to bet that `PATH` is supposed to be zero-terminated, and it does not appear to be. Is the carry flag set after the (invisible) `int 21h`? If so, what error number is in `ax`?

Comment: now u can see what is going on

Comment: Okay, that helps. I see you've zero-terminated `PATH`. Still not working? Okay, your macro returns with the carry-flag and `ax` untouched (that was the part I couldn't see). So check the carry flag after `@MkDir` - either `jc error` or `jnc good`. Should be set if it didn't work. If you don't have a routine to display `ax`, step through it (don't try to "step" through dos - use `p` when you get to the `int 21h`... assuming DEBUG). Look up the error code in RBIL (if you don't have it, get it!). Your code "looks" pretty good to me. "Should" work. :) May be a problem with permission to `C\:`?

Comment: Okay, error code for "access denied" is 5. Any other error is a mystery. If you're getting that, try running as root (I think Windows calls it "admin")... or try making a subdirectory in your current directory (just leave off the `c\:`). Courage!

Comment: When I changed MOV DX, offset PATH to LEA DX,PATH it creates and removes the directory but still doesn't creates file

Comment: file function works fine in E:. can you tell me how to give user input path

Comment: now every thing is fine except renaming of a file